# Iterate through Integer column in DataTable via For Next loop?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datatable

I am using a For Next loop to iterate through the columns of a Data Table.  One of those columns is a column of Booleans, for which the For Next code works.  However, the same code to iterate through the column of Integers does not work (?).

The error that I am getting I think I understand although how do I fix it?  Or can I simply not iterate through the row of integers with a For Next Loop?  Do I first need to dump that column of integers into an array, and then work with it?  I want this as simple as possible?  The most data that I would ever work with in this column is 50 elements.

The error that I'm getting when trying to iterate through the column of Integers is : "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

```
For Each [boolean] In sourceTable.Rows(0).Item(0)
            Try
                bools(i) = sourceTable.Rows(i).Item(0)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
            i += 1
        Next

        i = 0
        For Each [integer] In sourceTable.Rows(0).Item(3)
            Try
                intVals(i) = sourceTable.Rows(i).Item(3)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
            i += 1
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to loop over the Rows collection

```
Dim row As DataRow
For Each row In sourceTable.Rows
   Try
      Dim boolValue as Bool = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Item(0))
      ....
```

And the second loop is

```
For Each row In sourceTable.Rows
   Try
      Dim intValue = Convert.ToInt32(row.Item(3))
      ....
```

To use For Each (or a simple For) you need to have a collection to iterate over. The Rows is a collection while Rows(0).Item(0) means the field at position 0 in the first row. Clearly this is not a collection.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I guess what added to my confusion was the fact that the For Next Loop that I used for the Boolean data column worked as I coded it.  So naturally, my thought was, "Ok, well if that worked like that then doing the same code for the Integer data column should work the same way".  Knowing why it worked for the Booleans but not for the Integers would be helpful.